# Related question permuatation and combination 1

Tags: permutations, combinations

How to identify the question is permuatation or combination?

And below is some question:
i cannot solve.

[image: question]

Show how to solve it.
Thank you.

Comment: A permutation is a combination in which the order matters (i.e., different permutations of the same set of elements are considered as the same combination; that single combination is in fact the set of those elements).

Comment: First part:

Consider I, U, E clubbed together so now there are P, C, T, R and IUE, total $5$ "letters".

$5$ things can be arranged in $5!$ ways and IUE can be arranged in $3!$ ways among themselves, so total number of ways possible is $5!\times 3!$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A permutation is a combination of elements in which the order of the elements matters.

Different permutations of the same set of elements are considered as the same combination.

---

**Answering the first question:**

- The number of permutations of the set $\{P,C,T,R,EIU\}$ is $5!=120$
- The number of permutations of the set $\{P,C,T,R,EUI\}$ is $5!=120$
- The number of permutations of the set $\{P,C,T,R,IEU\}$ is $5!=120$
- The number of permutations of the set $\{P,C,T,R,IUE\}$ is $5!=120$
- The number of permutations of the set $\{P,C,T,R,UEI\}$ is $5!=120$
- The number of permutations of the set $\{P,C,T,R,UIE\}$ is $5!=120$

So the total number of permutations is $120+120+120+120+120+120=720$

---

**Answering the second question:**

- The number of permutations of $2$ girls in $2$ seats is $\binom22\cdot2!=2$
- The number of permutations of $4$ boys in $3$ seats is $\binom43\cdot3!=24$

So the total number of permutations is $2\cdot24=48$

---

**Answering the third question:**

- The number of permutations of numbers that end with $2$ is $3!=6$
- The number of permutations of numbers that start with $5$ and end with $4$ is $2!=4$
- The number of permutations of numbers that start with $7$ and end with $4$ is $2!=4$

So the total number of permutations is $6+4+4=14$

---

As you can see, each one of these questions is a "permutation question" (the second one being "slightly combinational", because you need to calculate a combination of $m$ out of $n$ items).

Comment: why want multiplication, not add 24+2??

Comment: @user2534252: Because the arrangements are independent of each other. For each way you arrange the girls, you have $24$ ways to arrange the boys (and for each way you arrange the boys, you have $2$ ways to arrange the girls).

Comment: and i want ask the q1, why uie become 1 not 3 ?

Comment: @user2534252: Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: P,C,T,R,E,I,U not 7!?
why become P,C,T,R,EIU 5!?

Comment: @user2534252: The question says "$3$ vowels must be side by side next to each other"!!!

Answer (score 0):

1st question is of permutation and its answer is : $(3! \cdot 5)4!$.. because if its the question of combination, then it is clear that .. the order is not important. What we have asked in question deals with order, so obviously it deals with permutation. You can see barak manos' answer for this question

2nd question confuses me because how can 6 persons seat in 5 chairs? [otherwise a girl sit on a boy's lap :p]
this question is little bit tricky, it involves both of permutation and combinations. because you gotta choose 5 persons among 6,

3rd question is also obvious as the first question, do it with your strength.